# Batch editor for text or html files?

Tags: software-recommendation, automation, text-editor, html, batch

is there a tool that can help me to batch edit text files in a certain folder?

I need to delete or insert snippets repeatedly in lots of html files and restructure them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Julian showed, `sed` is the right tool for that.

I just want to add two remarks:

you can process multiple files at once, just by providing list of files:

```
sed -i.bak 's/old text/new text/' dir1/*.html dir2/*.html
```

Also, if you need to work with some Snippets manually, you can enable Snippets plugin in gedit:

Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins -> Snippets. You might find it handy.

Answer (score 8):

sed, the stream editor, is your friend here. For example.

```
sed -i.bak -e's/<p id="first"/<p id="second"/' file.html
```

would change all the paragraphs with the id 'first' to id 'second' in file.html, and create file.html.bak into the bargain.

Comment: `ed` also can be a viable solution, if the *stream* requirement can be relaxed.